# Import cv2 working in terminal (after typing python3) but not in Pycharm

Tags: opencv, python-3.6

Import cv2 working in terminal (after typing python3) but not in Pycharm. In Pycharm, I get the following message:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

I have installed opencv and the Project Interpreter is Python3.6 in PyCharm.

System paths by using sys.path are:

From Terminal I get:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/m3z47/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

From PyCharm, I get:

```
['/home/m3z47/PycharmProjects/Rephrase', '/home/m3z47/PycharmProjects/Rephrase', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/m3z47/PycharmProjects/Rephrase/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/m3z47/PycharmProjects/Rephrase/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg', '/home/m3z47/PycharmProjects/Rephrase/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg']
```

Comment: print sys.path both from terminal and from spider, then figure out what is the difference.

Comment: Added the system paths in the question.

Comment: As you can see, the paths differ. Find out, where you have installed the `cv2` module and add the path in PyCharm